# Passport Local Strategy with Custom Callback Never Works

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I have struggled so much with Passport because the custom callback feature simply does not work. Here's how I initialize passport:

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Set up passport
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'userId',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, function (userId, password, cb) {
    users.findByUserId(userId, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return cb(null, false);
        } else {
            if (user.password !== password) {
                return cb(null, false);
            }
            return cb(null, user);
        }
    });
}));
passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
    cb(null, user.userId);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, cb) {
    users.findByUserId(id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return cb(err); }
        cb(null, user);
    });
});
```

Then, this is how it's SUPPOSED to log a user in when a user posts to '/login':

```
exports.tryLogin = function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return res.status(500).json({ success : false, message : 'Internal server error: ' + err.message }); }
        if (!user) { return res.status(500).json({ success : false, message : 'user not found'}); }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) { return res.status(500).json({ success : false, message : 'Internal server error: ' + err.message }); }
          return res.status(200).json({ success : true });
        });
      })(req, res, next);
}
```

Here's how I have to do it because it never detects the user. The 'user' in the above method is always undefined. I have to construct it from the request myself to get it to work:

```
exports.tryLogin = function (req, res, next) {
    var user = {
        userId: req.body.userId,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ success : false, message : 'Internal server error: ' + err.message });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded' });
    });
}
```

This works, but feels wrong because I'm never calling passport.authenticate. Is this ok or should I be banging my head against the wall trying to get the custom callback to work as defined in the documentation?

Sam

Comment: I will also try to help you with your problems with ```custom callback feature```. But I need more details, after you answer me then I update my response

Comment: ```custom callback feature simply does not work.``` 
what do you mean? What is custom callback? how this 'not working' manifests itself ?

Comment: In your first code snippet there is part ```users.findByUserId``` what is ```users``` object? I assume that this is your orm model? Where you define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is wrong approach.

This code means:

```
exports.tryLogin = function (req, res, next) {
    var user = {
        userId: req.body.userId,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    req.logIn(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({ success : false, message : 'Internal server error: ' + err.message });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success : true, message : 'authentication succeeded' });
    });
}
```

that You do not check permissions, You practically login anybody without password check.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I see what you mean by logging in anybody. The custom callback I need is the one as defined here in the docs: http://passportjs.org/docs (search for "custom callback" on this page). I basically just need to use this in order to send http responses when a user logs in, instead of doing a redirect, which is the other option passport provides.

Comment: 'Users' is the service I used to manage access to the users database. I'm basically doing queries to find the user in the database, like so:

    connection.query("select * from user_table where userId='" + userId + "'     ", function (err, user) {});

I'm positive that my users module is working because once logged in everything works fine and the account can be accessed, updated, etc.

Comment: how this 'not working' manifests itself? if you put console.log in this custom callback is it show in terminal?

Comment: and something very trivial, do you have in your code this ```app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended":true}));``` and ```app.use(passport.initialize());```

Comment: Yes I have those, thanks. What's happening is the 'user' returned in the custom callback is always undefined.

Comment: before this code ```users.findByUserId``` add console.log(userId);console.log(password); and do you get it values? Do you use session, is it configured?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92433/discussion-between-samuel-kilada-and-krzysztof-sztompka).

Comment: So, the answer to this was a bit unusual. For some reason logging to the console in the passport.use area of the code had never worked for me before (that is, it never showed up in the logs). Your suggestion to add logs helped because it finally started working for some reason. I realized that the issue is unrelated to passport but due to the fact that the user's password can change (since Google is used to sign in on my site), and the "password" changes each time you sign in and get a new token from Google. Thus it was denying the login. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: FYI, it's not letting me award the bounty for 22 hours, I promise I will when I can. Send me a ping if I don't.

Comment: I am glad that it is ok, now. I could not join because it my timezone was midnight